# Playing sequence of sound reminders in background pausing music and not stopped by other sounds

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I want to write application for iPhone which play the sequence of audio reminders and communicate in a good way with sounds produced by other applications.

To be more specific I want to achieve following points:
1. Play sound reminder every 10 seconds. (this is to simplify question, in my app there is a sequence of time moment, which specifies when to play reminders)
2. Sound should work in background.
3. If music plays it should be paused, my application should produce audio reminder, then music resumed.
4. If other applications start to use sound, my sequence of reminders should continue to work (e.g. music started or incoming call after my application ran).

With the code below I was able to achieve points 1. and 2. But I can not realize how to achieve 3. and 4. at the same time.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
}

// Following function is used to start reproducing sounds and also called
// for the next sounds
- (IBAction)soundPlayShort:(id)sender
{
    NSURL * url = @"reminder sound url here";

    // soundPlayer is defined in .h file as AVAudioPlayer
    if (soundPlayer == nil) {
       // initialize soundPlayer
       soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
       soundPlayer.delegate = self;
    }
    [soundPlayer playAtTime:soundPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + 10];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];    
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self soundPlayShort:self];
}
```

If I update `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` as in code below, other sounds are resumed (point 3.), but next reminder in my sequence does not called any more (related to point 2.)

```
- (void)restoreOtherSounds
{
    [audioSession setActive:NO 
        withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveFlags_NotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

    [self restoreOtherSounds];
    [self soundPlayShort:self];
}
```

And I have not realized how to resume reminder sequence e.g. after incoming call. (point 4)

Even partial answers could be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Related to point 2,Try setting the audio session as active before initialising AVAudioPlayer in soundPlayShort:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`